# In-App Billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION give DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i'm implementing in-app billing in my app. 
I just implemented REQUEST_PURCHASE, CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION and CHECK_BILLING, and they works fine.

Now i'm trying to implement REQUEST_TRANSACTIONS method, but i have a problem, once i sent the request with sendBIllingRequest, i receive a RESPONSE_CODE response with RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR (5).

This is how i make the request:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "Action equals RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
request.putLong("NONCE", BillingSecurity.newNonce());
try {
    Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
    int response_code = response.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE", -1);
    Log.d(TAG, "RESPONSE Restore: " + response_code);
    restored=true;
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I read on other questions, that RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS need to be launched when debug mode is disabled. I disabled it from The Manifest (i cleared the field, because if i put false LogCat didn't show any debug print), so this is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="resistorcalc.main"
  android:versionName="3.0" android:versionCode="9">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".App" android:icon="@drawable/resistoricon">
    <activity android:name=".launchActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SupportusActivity" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="OhmLawActivity" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ResistorSumActivity" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>               
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"/>
    <service android:name=".billing.BillingService" />

    <receiver android:name=".billing.BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>               
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Now my questions are:

1. I need to put false on Debuggable flag on the manifest? Or i just need to run the application.
2. Why logcat doesn't show any Log.* message if debuggable is se to false? It is a normal Behaviour (i'm using logcat inside eclipse)
3. If i use the static requests like android.test.purchased, they can be retrieved using RESTOrE_TRANSACTIONS?
4. Do i need to upload the draft on my market in order to have that method working?

Thanks, 
Ivan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debug flag in the manifest has nothing to do with this. You need to sign your app with you release key and upload a draft to the Play Store. You might have to wait for an hour or so for it to get activated too. And no, RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS does not work with the test items, you need to use your own published item. All of this is [described in the reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html), you shouldn't have any problems if you follow it.